# React app changes the font after page refresh

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating a ReactJS application and when the page charge, the font is one, and after reloading, the page is another. For an example, see the cases:

Before reloading (press f5):

[image]

After reloading (press f5):

[image]

In the past, I had a similar issue and resolved it by adding `style="all: unset"` in the body of the `index.html`, but it is not working for me now. Does anyone know you to fix it?

Comment: Check in dev tools if font loads

Comment: W/o any code this is probably very hard to answer. There could be some general purpose troubleshooting like check for the font and possibly if you are redirecting from a page to this page and then hitting refresh it must be that this font is getting lost smh. Other than that your font is getting loaded with a delay probably with a n/w request and so and before it loads the page loaded up this could be possible.

Comment: Actually, I'm on the login page and, after handling the login, I'm redirecting to this page. The font is really getting lost... But I don't know how to treat it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to give you clear answer without code. There could be various reasons.
here is why:

1. It could be because of Caching.(you pressed F5) Sometimes font file is being cached by the browser, so please check it with using Guest mode in chrome. To prevent caching of font, Please add a cache-busting query parameter to the font URL by adding version number to font url.
2. It could be because of loading time of font. If your project or CSS file size is not small, then it will take some time to load fonts from online service such as google font platform. In this case, The chrome displays the default font as font is not loaded at the moment. So, After some times, Font style will be set as correct. In order to solve this problem, you can download the font assets and save it in assets folder of your project. Or you can use font-display: swap; property.
3. There could be CSS conflicts. Check if there are any CSS rules or styles being applied globally.

Anyway, For more detailed solution, providing code is absolute must.
Hope this could be helpful for your problems. Thank you.